# android room dao has higher repetition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

i find every db operation need a method

if a class has n fields, I want each field to be queried individually, I hava to write n methods.

If any two fields are queried together, I hava to write n*(n-1) methods.

```kotlin
// example
@Entity(
    tableName = "any_table",
)
data class AnyTable(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Long = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "key1") var key1: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "key2") var key2: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "key3") var key3: String,
) {
    @Dao
    interface OperationDao {
        @Query("SELECT * FROM any_table")
        suspend fun query(): List<AnyTable>

        @Query("SELECT * FROM any_table where key1 = :key")
        suspend fun queryByKey1(key: Int): List<AnyTable>

        @Query("SELECT * FROM any_table where key2 = :key")
        suspend fun queryByKey2(key: Boolean): List<AnyTable>

        @Query("SELECT * FROM any_table where key3 = :key")
        suspend fun queryByKey3(key: String): List<AnyTable>

        @Query("SELECT * FROM any_table where key1 = :key1 and key2 = :key2")
        suspend fun queryByKey1AndKey2(key1: Int, key2:Boolean): List<AnyTable>

        @Query("SELECT * FROM any_table where key1 = :key1 and key3 = :key3")
        suspend fun queryByKey1AndKey3(key1: Int, key3:String): List<AnyTable>

    }
}
```

this way is so cockamamie fussy, Why is there no tool to automatically generate interfaces ?

or I just want a default dao that is automatic adaptation its class and every field.

Comment: it looks ok But when it comes to the production level app. it is not acceptable to have so many useless methods in the project. not everyone wants to get a query by every parameter and also as you have suggested with many parameters. in most cases, 2 or 3 parameters are key to selecting that row for use. you will get a better idea when you generate more and more database files for your project.

Comment: ok, I achieve a Library, its code style is like https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed , it can solove this problem